# 2 Users One Computer Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, google-chrome-os

I had a question on how would you set up a remote desktop system where there would be one computer with one monitor connected via HDMI and one Chromebook which is connected wirelessly.

This system would have the Chromebook user being remotely connected and is playing games, the monitor user is doing its own thing(studying)

Computer Specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7
GPU: GTX 1080
64 bit
Windows 10

Chromebook Specs:
CPU: Potato(Intel M3)
GPU: Integrated
Chrome OS(Can download Android Apps)

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy, but is there a VNC server for Windows that would enable this? That's the easy way for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method of accomplishing this in Windows.  A remote desktop session will take over the current desktop session.  I dont know of any 3rd party tools that can accomplish this, or if there are any.

I dont know if the following will work, but it is worth a shot.  It is *possible* to [install Steam on a Chromebook](https://www.google.com/search?q=steam%20for%20chromebook&oq=steam%20for%20chrom&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2622j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  If that works, it might be possible to use [Steam Remote Play](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay/) to play Steam games installed on the PC from the Chromebook via streaming.

Comment: If I were to do this could the user with the computer alt+tab and do his/her's own thing, while I from the Chromebook with Steam Remote Play can play the game?

Comment: @TacticDev Steam would just need to be running, not active.  You wouldnt even need to alt-tab.  I do want to reiterate, I have not tried this, I do not know if it will work.  But it shouldnt hurt to try.

Answer (score 1):

Option1: You could run a virtual machine (a second Windows) on your laptop and connect with the Chromebook to the VM, also via RDP.

Option2: There are a few hacks, that allow you to use to user sessions simultaneously into "the same" windows. But all of them are not legal when it comes to licensing.

Option3: You could choose a tool like Teamviewer or Anydesk to logon from different locations, but they will all connect to the same windows user session.

Option4: The only other Microsoft option, but probable not a solution for your use case, is to use a windows server and setup remote desktop services role and the purchase of licenses to enable additional RDP connections (if you need more the two simultaneous connections). But that is a question for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://ehikioya.com/multiple-rdp-sessions-in-windows-rdp-wrapper-library/). It's not really clear whether or not you can use the console during a rdp session, but it does explain how to do two concurrent rdp sessions. I haven't tried it myself - I'll try to have a go later today and update this.